# вывести в шаблон информацию (из второго массива)

Tags: python, django

Запарился на такой мелочи, но не могу понять как вывести именно следующий массив)

Есть такое:

```
return render(request, 'main.html', {'arrImages': arrImages,'title': arrTitle})
```

Массив `arrImages` выводится без проблем.
Но как вывести `title`? Не понимаю где нужно loop-ить.

```
<div class="container">
{% for images in arrImages %}
<hr>
    <p class="text-justify"> {{ /////????title }}</p>
    <img class = "col-12 ml-auto col-12 mr-auto" src={{ images }}>
{% endfor %}
```

Куда бы я не поставил, не работает, или это делается одним циклом? 
Сорри за такие вопросы, но в инете не нашел)

код views.py

```
def main(request):
    d3 = requests.get('https://d3.ru/api/posts/?sorting=rating&threshold_date=day').json()
    arrImages = []
    arrTitle = []
    arrText = []
    try:
        for data in d3['posts']:
            imagesPath= ('data', 'link','url')
            images = reduce(lambda c, k: c[k] if c is not None and k in c else None, imagesPath, data)
            if images is not None and ".gif" in images and ".gifv" not in images:
                arrImages.append(images)
            imagesPath2= ('data', 'media','url')
            images2 = reduce(lambda c, k: c[k] if c is not None and k in c else None, imagesPath2, data)
            if images2 is not None:
                arrImages.append(images2)
                titlePath= ('data', 'title')
                textPath= ('data', 'text')
                title = reduce(lambda c, k: c[k] if c is not None and k in c else None, titlePath, data)
                text = reduce(lambda c, k: c[k] if c is not None and k in c else None, textPath, data)
                if title is not None:
                    arrTitle.append(title)
                if text is not None:
                    arrText.append(text)

        print('arrImages',arrImages)
        print('title',arrTitle)
        print('text',arrText)
    except BaseException as e:
        print('ecxeptions: ',e)
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'arrImages': arrImages,'title': arrTitle})
```

Comment: {% for item in title %} - не работает?

Comment: не работает, а чего записи разнятся? По аналогии  должно же быть {% for title in arrTitle%} вроде?)

Comment: Тогда уж должно быть не `for images in arrImages`, а `{% for i in range(len(arrImages)) %}`, а потом в нужных местах `{{ arrImages[i] }}` и `{{ title[i] }}`

Comment: @Romik romikromik - нет, в качестве названия переменной используется ключ { ..., 'title': arrTitle }, как видишь у тебя ключ - это title, соотвественно итерировать нужно так же по нему

Comment: «а чего записи разнятся?» — так вы же сами в коде написали разное `'title': arrTitle`

Comment: покажите откуда берется arrImages и arrTitle, как они друг с другом связаны? возможно стоит добавить код вью и модели

Comment: @СергейЧабаненко обновил, тело вопроса.  Я работаю через апи, без базы данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как это выглядит :

```
return render(request, 'main.html', {'imageTitles': zip(arrImages, arrTitle)})
```

Затем:

```
<div class="container">
    {% for image, title in imageTitles %}
    <hr>
        <p class="text-justify">{{ title }}</p>
        <img class = "col-12 ml-auto col-12 mr-auto" src={{ image}}>
    {% endfor %}
```